# How to emit changes when mat-slider is moved?

Tags: angular

I have the following slider:

```
<mat-slider
tickInterval="1000"
thumbLabel
(change)="opacityBackgroundChange($event)"
[(ngModel)]="opacityBackgroundColor"
step="0.01"
min="0"
max="1"
></mat-slider>
```

Why `(change)` works only when mouse is push down? How to emit values duting movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the API for MatSlider: https://material.angular.io/components/slider/api

There is also:

```
@Output()
input: EventEmitter<MatSliderChange>
```

property you can use:

```
<mat-slider
  ...
  (input)="onInput($event)"
  ...
></mat-slider>
```